# How extract a field from file with awk without separators in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh, separator

I've got a file calling "file" where there are some fields separated with a separator. The structure of the file is:

```
@field1@field2@field3@field4
```

With awk i've extracted the fields without separators.

```
vr=$file;

sep_mx=`echo $vr | awk '{
    n=split($0,x,"@");
    print n
}'` 
echo $sep_mx
## here the number of substring produced is calc.

while ((i<=$max)); 
do
    # would print individual substring one at a
    # time as the counter increases.
    echo $vr | awk -v er=$i '{
        n=split($0,x,"@"); print x[er]
    }'
    ((i+=1))
done
```

The output is:

```
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

If i want to extract only the second field from the code i've just posted how can i do it? Thanks

Comment: The script you posted cannot produce the posted output from the posted input. You should update your post to show the script you're actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash`:

```
$ while IFS=@ read -r col1 col2 col3 col4; do 
      echo $col3
  done <<< '@field1@field2@field3@field4'
field2
```

Another way with `awk`

```
$ awk '{split($0,ary,/@/); print ary[3]}' <<< '@field1@field2@field3@field4'
field2
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will not work with files with multiple lines of this pattern. Using `awk` with `$3` will operate over the 3rd column of *all* lines in the file.

Comment: Why would you use split() on $1 instead of just assigning FS and letting awk split the record into fields naturally? Also, the way you have it will fail if the text between the first 2 "@" symbols contains any white space.

Comment: @EdMorton Split should work now, I changed the solution to use `$0` instead of `$1`

Comment: @Jaypal yes, it will function correctly now, but it still doesn't make sense to do it that way vs `awk -F@ '{print $3}'`.

Comment: @EdMorton I know, I was just offering another way of splitting. Fedorqui already stated the answer with `-F`, so I thought this will become as a good reference for OP.

Comment: @Jaypal well, if we're posting referential alternatives you shouldn't use, you should include a while loop using index() and substr() and a loop with FS="" testing each character for "@" and ..... :-). The thing is there's no way for someone who doesn't know awk to figure out from your post that you would definitely NOT suggest that they actually do that to solve this problem. Is the bash solution also something you would NOT suggest they use?

Comment: Second way works thanks. But if i want an output with quotes? I mean `'field2'` instead of `field2`

Comment: @End.Game You can do something like `awk 'BEGIN { f="'"'"'" } {split($0,ary,/@/); printf "%s\n", f ary[3] f}' <<< '@field1@field2@field3@field4'`

Answer (score 5):

This should make it:

```
awk -F@ '{print $3}' file
```

In general, try to use `-F`. It means "field separator" and makes your life easier, with no needs to split, substr and things like that.

#### Test

```
$ awk -F@ '{print $3}' file
field2
```

Comment: Thanks, but if my separator is something like "@#"? I think i can't write `$ awk -F@# '{print $3}' file` right?

Comment: +1 I like how the question was about solving the problem *not* using a separator and the answer here being *use* a separator. Funny.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I should have stuck to *not using* a separator, but I found it important to highlight `-F` in awk, as it is such a powerful tool for these situations.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU sed invocation

```bash
sed -r 's/\W\w+\W(\w+).*/\1/' file
```

outputs

```
field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense. If want to convert

```
@field1@field2@field3@field4
```

to

```
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

then all you need is this (or any of various other simple solutions):

```
$ cat file
@field1@field2@field3@field4
$ 
$ gawk -v RS='[@\n]' 'NR>1' file
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

If you want to print text "field3" then it's simply:

```
$ gawk -v RS='[@\n]' 'NR==4' file 
field3
```

The record number is 4 instead of 3 because your file starts with "@" so there's an empty record before "field1".

If you tell us what you're really trying to do we can help you, so far you seem to be going down the wrong path.